# How to determine database relations from PASE/Qshell?

Tags: shell, ksh, ibm-midrange

I'm just stepping into the world of PASE and Qshell on the IBM i, and am still learning the "shell way" of solving problems.

I'm trying to write a shell script that will delete all logical files in a given library that are associated with a given physical file.  The OS is IBM i 7.2.  In QSYS-land, I'd probably `DSPDBR` on the physical file to an outfile, then read through the outfile and delete each dependent file.  How would you do this in PASE or Qshell?  I had a couple ideas, but they all seem overly-complicated, and the more I learn about shell scripting, the more shortcuts I'm finding.

My first idea was to basically replicate the above process, doing something like this and then somehow using the output of the SELECT:

```
system "DSPDBR FILE(MYLIB/MYFILE) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/DSPDBR)"
db2 "select WHREFI from QTEMP/DSPDBR where WHRELI = 'MYLIB'"
```

(I see now that QTEMP doesn't really work as a temporary library, but maybe there's a way around this.)

My second idea was to do something like pipe the output of the DSPDBR statement into something like awk to pick out the logical file names, and redirect the output of that to a stream file (or shell variable?).  And from there, somehow use this list to delete the logical files.

Is there a more straightforward approach?  It seems like whatever the answer is, it will be a pattern that is often repeated when writing shell scripts to interact with QSYS commands and objects.

Answer (score 1):

First, you might review [Running SQL queries from PASE instead of QSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/692140/running-sql-queriesfrom-pase-instead-of-qsh). The db2 utility is part of Qshell and not PASE. Unfortunately, the processing behind it is based in ILE, so it's not directly usable within the PASE (AIX run-time) environment. The linked question provides a method of bridging between the two.

However, directly in QShell, you can experiment with something like this:

```
db2 "SELECT substr(VIEW_NAME,1,18), substr(OBJECT_NAME,1,10),
       substr(OBJECT_SCHEMA,1,10), substr(VIEW_SCHEMA,1,10),
       substr(TABLE_NAME,1,18)
 FROM qsys2.sysviewdep
 WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA = '<yourSchemaName>'"
```

The SUBSTR() functions might or might not be useful. It depends on your name lengths and whether you want them limited or not. The output can be redirected to an outfile or perhaps piped into sed or another utility for manipulation.

Comment: QSYS2.SYSVIEWDEP doesn't seem to contain my test PFs and LFs, for some reason. Maybe the LFs are considered to be indexes and so aren't included in SYSVIEWDEP?

Comment: I think what I'm more looking for is the general pattern people use when writing shell scripts on the i that need to interact with QSYS commands/programs.  In my LF scenario above, I'm wondering what the right way is to get a list of LFs for a given PF.  Should the script call a program I write in QSYS to get the list?  Should it parse the piped output of the DSPDBR command?  Should it work with an output file generated by DSPDBR?  When trying to manipulate QSYS objects and get metadata about them from within a shell, what are the common patterns people use?

Comment: @smeep Can you edit your question to clarify those last bits? (Comments can be temporary.) Are you more interested in PASE? QShell is relatively well integrated with the OS while PASE can require more specific programming to replicate or access IBM i features within an AIX run-time.

Answer (score 1):

A QTEMP library is specific to [is scoped to] the process that implements the request in the shell.  Ensure all of the requests that depend on the same QTEMP library will run in the same process; the *system* utility runs in a separate process, as does the *db2* utility.  For example, in the following command-line invocation of the QSHell, all of the requests dependent on QTEMP will run in the same process in which the *db2* utility runs; the *db2* utility runs a script [or could instead run a dynamic compound statement] that in this scenario was generated by the scripted requests for\within the shell utility:

```
 qsh cmd('                                                                 
   echo "call qsys2.qcmdexc                                                
           (''dspdbr mylib/myfile output(*outfile) outfile(qtemp/dspdbr)'')
        " >> mydb2.script                                                  
 ; echo "select WHREFI from QTEMP.DSPDBR where WHRELI =''MYLIB''           
        " >> mydb2.script                                                  
 ; db2 -f    mydb2.script                                                  
 ; rm        mydb2.script                                                  
         ')
```

Comment: Is the key here that qsys2.qcmdexc -- unlike `system` -- runs within the parent process (in this case `db2`), and so the select statement sees the same QTEMP library as DSPDBR?

Comment: Correct; the stored procedure CALL is performed synchronously within the same process as the prior and later scripted requests.  
All of the scripted requests made within one `db2` invocation will run in the separate process that was started for that `db2` invocation, for which, as with all processes, that QTEMP library will persist until the process terminates, shared across all requests that run within that process.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source equivalent of the QShell db2 command: https://bitbucket.org/litmis/db2util